# How do add a C++.winRT blank page to a c++/wint Blank App - using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++-winrt

I have created a Blank App (Universal Windows). It creates a MainPage.xaml automatically.I want to add a second page. When I select Add a New Item, XAML, 
it createst a C++/cx blank page with no idl.

My question - what is the proper method to add a C++/winRT blank page to a Visual Studio Ap?

Comment: Mixing C++/CX and C++/WinRT in the same project is [non-trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39775875/1889329). You are best advised to install the [C++/WinRT Visual Studio extension](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt/vsix), and create a project using the *"Blank App (C++/WinRT)"* project template.

Comment: Problem solved: I had to rebuild my system - I forgot to reinstall C++/winRT VSIX.